# How to Capture and Handle PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a clean window with a Border inside of, I want handle the MouseClick if it was out that border.
I tried this code but it didn't work:

[image]

Code behind:

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(onmousedown), true);
        Mouse.Capture(this.border,CaptureMode.Element);

    }

    private void onmousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

please help me, or guide me how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my Problem by creating a simple Control looks like:
The thing that i got is initialize the capture in the load event.

```
 public class ModulesMenuControl : Control
    {          
 static ModulesMenuControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ModulesMenuControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ModulesMenuControl)));
        }

        public ModulesMenuControl()
        {
            this.Loaded += MouseCaptureControl_Loaded;
        }

        void MouseCaptureControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            this.AddHandler(Mouse.PreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(onmousedown), true);
            Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);
        }

        private void onmousedown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("out click");
        }
```

Comment: Capturing the mouse on the Loaded event did the trick! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `MouseDown` event to the `Window` (or parent control) and you can use the `MouseButtonEventArgs` to work out which element was clicked. Here's an example:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" MouseDown="GridMouseDown">
    <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
</Grid>
```

And in your C# code:

```
private void GridMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //use e.Source to check which element was clicked, like this:
    if (e.Source.GetType() == typeof(Border))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The border was clicked");
    }

    //Or, you can check the name of the element, like this:
    if (((FrameworkElement)e.Source).Name == "myBorderName")
    {
        //Something useful.
    }
}
```

Comment: it may the border have controls like buttons ... it didn't work for me. the Source becomes the item that clicked.